# Extending the size of ubuntu partition

Tags: 12.10, 10.04, partitioning

I have a computer which have windows 7,Ubuntu 10.04 and Ubuntu 12.10 respectively. This is my partition table

[image]

The 21 GB ext4 is the primary partition of Ubuntu 12.10 and 18 GB ext4 is of Ubuntu 10.04. Now I want to uninstall Ubuntu 12.10 and add this space to Ubuntu 10.04. How can I do this?
Since I use the grub of Ubuntu 12.10 is it possible to do without harming this boot-loader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a LiveCD like PartedMagic (http://www.partedmagic.com) with GParted available and use GParted to:

1. Remove the Partition with 12.10 on it.
2. Move the Partition called Softwares to the left (Don't know if this will change the  drive Letter assigned to it in windows, so be sure you know how to assign drive letters to drives on windows if you have any programs installed to this partition)
3. Grow the partition with 10.04 on it to fill the free space.

In order to repair your bootloader, you somehow have to boot your 10.04. I recommend using SuperGrubDisk 2 (available as standalone LiveCD on http://www.supergrubdisk.org and already integrated in PartedMagic). When you have successfully booted your Ubuntu 10.04, run the following commands to reinstall your bootloader:

- `sudo update-grub`
- `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`

Since you are messing around with both partitions and your bootsector, be sure to have a backup of all your important data as doing something wrong or having powerloss while partitioning may destroy your data and if in doubt, asking is better than walking into a catastrophy.

Comment: how to move software to the left?

Comment: Simply use GPartEd to do this, there is a button with either an arrow or the text "move/resize partitions". once you clicked that, you can drag the partition with your mouse to the  left. (After deleting 12.10 of course). Growing 10.04 works with the same button, but you have to resize the partition with your mouse like resizing a window, by dragging the border.